# working with large images in android

Tags: android, bitmap, weak-references

I have an app in android in which I'm working with really big images`(640x480)` and slightly bigger.This are actually pictures taken with the camera, then are edited, after that are saved to `sdcard` and finally uploaded to a server.
  But the issue that I'm facing is `VM memory exceeded` when working with `bitmaps`.

I'm doing something like this:

In the first activity I'm receiving `the bytes from the camera` and create a `bitmap` which is edited and then saved to `sdcard`

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        options.inDither = true; 
        byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
        myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length, options);

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);

        if(myImage !=null){
        bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage.get(), 0, 0, (myImage.get()).getWidth(),
                (myImage.get()).getHeight(), mat, true);
```

in `onPause()` method I did this:

```
 bitmapResult.recycle();
  bitmapResult=null;
```

In my second activity I'm reading the file from `sdcard` and display it on the screen.Why?I have my reasons:

```
File f=new File("/sdcard/Images/android.jpg");  
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        o2.inSampleSize=8;
        o2.outWidth=100;
        o2.outHeight=100;

        try {
            x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         if(x != null){

             myImage.setImageBitmap(x);
                }
```

And did the same thing in `onPause()`

```
x.recycle();
x=null;
```

All this didn't worked and after taking a few pictures my app crashed.

I tried using `WeaakReference` instead of `bitmap`:

```
myImage = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length, options));
```

And still nothing....the same error....`out of memory`.

Has anyone any idea?

P.S: I also tried to call `System.gc()` but with the same result!

So please help me!

Comment: Declare All Variables/Objects Globally.

Comment: they are globally in every activity:)...this is the way they are

Comment: Variables/Objects Means Bitmap, Drawable etc., and set null on last part of the activity.

Comment: If You Are In First Activity that time u r saved image in sdcard and in second activity u r displayed this image on display.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3171/discussion-between-dipak-keshariya-and-george)

Comment: Do you have to get bytearray from Bitmap ? If you are not manipulating pixel by pixel, then you can avoid getting byte array, thus saving memory. Instead you can use methods provided in Bitmap class for manipulation. I have been using multiple bitmaps of WVGA size, and not encountering out of memory issue !!

Comment: if u could provide a piece of code how to that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code to resize the image**

`

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();
float scaleWidth = ((float) 300) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) 300) / height;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width,
            height, matrix, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream baostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baostream);
```

`